# Visual Studio 2010 IDE Find Options Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, find

I have an overloaded method which have these signatures:

```
void Method(string a,string b);

void Method(string a,string b,string c);

void Method(string a,string b,string c,string d,string e);
```

What I want to do in Visual Studio IDE is to find all lines in the current project where **Method** is called with only less than 5 parameters (e.g. the first and second signatures in the example). 
Is it possible to do this (or any plugin *resharper etc.* is able to that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex in the find window:

```
(Method\(([:a:b]+,[:a:b]*)^1\))|(Method\(([:a:b]+,[:a:b]*)^2\))|(Method\(([:a:b]+,[:a:b]*)^3\))
```

It's an **OR** basically of:

```
(Method\(([:a:b]+,[:a:b]*)^N\))
```

where N looks for N of alpha or whitespace followed by a comma

Answer (score 0):

You can search with regexp, so you should be able to do something like "/void[]Method\(([^\)^,]+,){1,3}\)/". I don't know if it is the exact syntax, but you have the idea.